# Hide/Show animations on ngShow

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, css-animations

I'm trying to do some sort of presentation with AngularJS and I wanted to use the power of ngAnimation which, so far, has been massively hard.

I've been able to use `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` with CSS Transitions without much issue but right now, I'm stuck trying to work this out.

I want text to come from above, and when the next "slide" comes, current text should `fadeOutDown` and next text should `fadeInDown` as the previous one.

So, the classes should be like this:

```
.animation-fadeInDown-fadeOutDown.ng-hide-add,
.animation-fadeInDown-fadeOutDown.ng-hide-remove {
    display: table-cell !important;
}

.animation-fadeInDown-fadeOutDown.ng-hide-add {
    animation-duration: 1.5s;
    animation-name: fadeOutDown;
}

.animation-fadeInDown-fadeOutDown.ng-hide-remove {
    animation-delay: 10s;
    animation-duration: 1.5s;
    animation-name: fadeInDown;
}
```

What actually happens is that the two animations end up overlapping and shown incorrectly. I've prepared a [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/dyzxT5Ev9GBq0AOGRR8S?p=preview) with some boilerplate code that will show the problem as it is now. And you'll soon realize what's going on.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are not using the good CSS properties on your classes :

```
.animation-fadeInDown-fadeOutDown.ng-hide-add,
.animation-fadeInDown-fadeOutDown.ng-hide-remove
```

Try with the following CSS rules and it should solve your issue.

```
.animation-fadeInDown-fadeOutDown.ng-hide-add,
.animation-fadeInDown-fadeOutDown.ng-hide-remove {
  display:block!important;
}

.animation-fadeInDown-fadeOutDown.ng-hide-add {
  opacity : 1;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  -moz-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
  -webkit-animation-name: fadeOutDown;
  -moz-animation-name: fadeOutDown;
  animation-name: fadeOutDown;
}

.animation-fadeInDown-fadeOutDown.ng-hide-remove {
  opacity : 0;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1.5s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 1.5s;
  animation-delay: 1.5;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  -moz-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
  -webkit-animation-name: fadeInDown;
  -moz-animation-name: fadeInDown;
  animation-name: fadeInDown;
}
```

Working plunker over [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/l6Oj8pqF6UkImr23wMn7?p=preview)

Comment: Seems that the only significant difference was the `opacity` on both.

Comment: Can you please tell me why display:block !important is required and why we use it?